# Error in ogrInfo() Cannot open data source/Cannot open layer

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a .shp file with readOGR() but I keep getting one of two errors

When I use this code:

```
county.map <- readOGR(paste0("C:/Users/name/Documents/HospMarket/geog/cb_2017_us_county_5m.shp"),layer = "cb_2017_us_county_5m",verbose = FALSE)
```

I get this error:

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
> Cannot open data source

One fix I read about led me to write this instead:

```
county.map <- readOGR(paste0("C:/Users/name/Documents/HospMarket/geog"),layer = "cb_2017_us_county_5m",verbose = FALSE)
```

Here I get this error code:

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
> Cannot open layer

I am really at a loss of what else to do, I am 99.99% sure that everything is spelled correctly, what else could this mean? I am relatively new to R so I am still learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
library(rgdal)

county.map <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/name/Documents/HospMarket/geog", #Provide the directory of shp file
                      layer = "cb_2017_us_county_5m", #Provide the name of the shp file without extension (.shp)
                      verbose = FALSE)
```